# Get result from InputPrompt in Coding4Fun toolkit

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In the Coding4Fun toolkit you got a nice popup to ask the user for input.

```
    InputPrompt prompt = new InputPrompt();
        prompt.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        prompt.Completed += input_completed;
        prompt.Title = "Input title";
        prompt.Message = "Give a title for your note";
        prompt.Show();
```

If I generate the code for the "input_completed" I get:

```
   private void input_completed(object sender, PopUpEventArgs<string, PopUpResult> e)
        {

        }
```

I can't seem to find an answer to the simple question: how do I get the value out? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the result in form of string from the event args:

```
void input_completed(object sender, PopUpEventArgs<string, PopUpResult> e)
{
    string result = e.Result;
}
```